# numbers grouping in sap_bo

Tags: business-objects, webi

I'm having a problem in SAP BO-s that I'm trying to solve for a while now so I'm hoping to find a help here...
So, I have a list of orders and a number of items on each...

[image: input table]

... and a final result should be numbers grouping of numbers of items shown as dimension with number of orders shown as measure...

[image: output table]

I've tried with various combinations of `foreach` and in context operators but none of them seems to work. Does anyone have an idea how to do it? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The simpliest thing would be to use an object containing the number of items for each order as a dimension rather than a measure. Then you could create groups around the number of items. I am assume you cannot do that.

So start off by creating a variable to convert your **Number Of Items Dimension** to a string (and dimension) like this...

```
=FormatNumber([Items_no]; "#")
```

Next create a variable to count your orders...

```
=Count([Order_no])
```

Now adding those two variables to a table will give you the following...

[image]

In order to lump anything 6 or greater together you could create a variable with a series of nested if statements. In this situation it is much easier to create a group. To do so, right-click on the **Number of Items Dimension** column in the table just created, choose "Group > Manage Groups...", and create a group that looks something like this...

[image]

Sum the **Number of Orders** column and there you have it...

[image]